# How to echo foreach

Tags: php, xml, echo, explode

I am reading an xml file with

```
<imageref>image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg</imageref>
```

I explode the images as follow:

```
    foreach ($filtered as $hotel) {

    $image_array = explode('|', $hotel->imageref);
        foreach($image_array as $k => $img)
            $image[$k+1] = $img;

}
```

How can I echo each image into a div class?

I want the following result:

```
<div class"images">image1.jpg</div>
<div class"images">image2.jpg</div>
<div class"images">image3.jpg</div>
<div class"images">image4.jpg</div>
```

Comment: `echo '<img src="' . $img . '" />';`

Comment: I suggest to build entire string first. Then, echo it using one instruction. Echoing everything immediately is a terrible design and then other programmers have to maintain such bull##it :/ Just as @DanielWilliams wrote - one echo is better than dozens of echoes.

Comment: What exactly makes one echo better than many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the $k => $img as there is no key, only a value.

```
foreach($image_array as $img)
    {
    echo "<img src=".$img.">";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
foreach($image_array as $k => $img)
    echo "<div class='images'><img src='$img' /></div>";
```

?

Comment: sorry I changed my question

Comment: edited my answer. Shouldn't have been too difficult to change it by yourself, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $hotel is the content inside <imageref></imageref>

```
$image_array = explode("|",$hotel);

foreach($image_array AS $img) {
    echo '<div class"images">'.$img.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string  = '<imageref>image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg</imageref>';
$images  = explode('|', strip_tags($string));
foreach($images as $image) {
    printf('<div class="image">%s</div>', $image);
}
```